# Count wins from total turns in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently whenever I click the button in my `GameOfChance` component it will tell if my expression is true or false. In the state I set my count 0 and after every click + 1. My question is how do I count the wins? Right now it tells me Expression is not defined. How can I tell in my state that when expression is true or false it should count +1 or stay the same?

```
class Results extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.fiftyFifty ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!'
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}  

class GameOfChance extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            wins: 0,
            losses: 0
        }
    }

    increment = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1,
            wins: {expression} == true ? this.state.wins + 1 : this.state.wins
        })
    }


    render(){
        const expression = Math.random() > .5;
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.increment}>Gamble</button>
                <h1><Results fiftyFifty={expression} /></h1>
                <p>Total turns : {this.state.count}</p>
                <p>Wins: {this.state.wins}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. `expression` inside `increment` is not declared.! It is declared inside `render` as a const

Comment: Yes I know but how do I get this to work? is it possible in state or?

Comment: Why not add expression in state? If not, pass it as argument

Comment: If you need expression on every `click` event, maybe add it to your state along side  `count` and `wins`.

Comment: I would not store it inside state since there is really not reason to when you can just pass it to the `increment` function using a higher order function closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the result of your random number to the increment function like so

```
const Results = ({didWin}) => (didWin ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!')  

class GameOfChance extends React.Component{

    state = {
        count: 0,
        wins: 0,
        losses: 0
    }

    increment = (didWin) => (clickEvent) => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1,
            wins: didWin ? this.state.wins + 1 : this.state.wins
        })
    }


    render(){
        const didWin = Math.random() > .5;
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.increment(didWin)}>Gamble</button>
                <h1><Results didWin={didWin} /></h1>
                <p>Total turns : {this.state.count}</p>
                <p>Wins: {this.state.wins}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem! I also edited it to make `Results` as stateless functional component since you don't need any state inside it and I also removed the `<div>` since you can return a string and I assume you don't really want a `div` in your `h1`. Might be useful for you. Good luck with React!